# How to create abstract class for multiple forms?

Tags: forms, winforms, abstract-class

I have 2 function open 2 form that 2 form have the same method and property to 90% .

I'm thinking how to used the same code section. `Abstract class` perhaps a solution, but I don't know how it is supposed to work in c# with multiple forms.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.Thank you!

Comment: The exact same way as it would work for any other class. The only limitation is that you cannot use the designer on forms derived from abstract classes, so you may need to make a concession to practicality and *not* make the base class `abstract`.

Comment: Cody: thank you for reply. Because I'm newbie C#. Is there a good C# example of how to do this?

Comment: I'm sure there are. Google indexes a lot of interesting stuff. Did you try searching for keywords including "c#", "abstract", "form", and "class"? Note also that, as I said, there is really nothing special about forms. Any documentation on creating abstract classes would be useful. Consider purchasing a book that teaches you how to program in C# using Windows Forms. Questions like this are too broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Or post your code at [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) to see if it can be refactored intelligently.